# get_user_meta() to Return User Meta Only for Current Blog in Multi Site

Tags: multisite, user-meta

I've written a plugin that allows users to bookmark their favorite posts, but have run into a small problem when using it on a multisite network.

Each time a post is bookmarked, the ID of that post is stored in an array of IDs in the current user's meta table. This all works great, until it's used on a MS setup.

If viewing the site that the bookmarks were created on, everything works great, but when viewing a different site, I get a list of post IDs that belong to the other site. This is because the user meta table is shared between sites.

So, what I need to do is retrieve only the user meta for the current site. Is there a way to do this? I don't think there is, so if anyone has some insight, that'd be great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

WordPress distinguishes usermeta keys between sites by using the database prefix for each site.

For example, instead of using the favorite_posts key, you'd use the meta key wp_23_favorite_posts. To get the prefix, you can use `$wpdb->get_blog_prefix()`.

But wait, there's actually a whole API dedicated to this. Rather than using `*_user_meta()`, use `*_user_option()`. These are internally translated to be against the individual site.

And, it's easily integrated into your existing plugin. `get_user_option()` checks against a site-specific key first, but if it doesn't find anything, it falls back to a user-wide meta key. So go ahead and switch to `get_user_option()` and your existing plugin will work on single site without a problem.

Here are the function definitions:

```
./wp-includes/user.php:251:function get_user_option( $option, $user = 0 )
./wp-includes/user.php:293:function update_user_option( $user_id, $option_name, $new_value )
./wp-includes/user.php:322:function delete_user_option( $user_id, $option_name )
```

Comment: Oh, cool! I didn't know about get_user_option(). I will test it and let you know.

Comment: what is interesting is that if I want to delete a site wide piece of user meta I must use delete_user_meta() because if I use delete_user_option() it prefixes the option with 'wp_' - which I'm guessing is the default site prefix.

Comment: Seems this person wants only the user meta for a specific site.  How is using `get_user_option` supposed to help when it falls back to a user-wide meta key?  user-wide here soulds like the full network.  But don't want the network, just a site.  Don't want the fallback here.  So this seems like it does not help any.

Answer (score 4):

why not store the blog id together with the array of postIds, so you will have something like this stored in the user meta data:

```
Array
(
   [blogid1] => Array(1,2,4,7),
   [blogid2] => Array(3,6,8,10)
)
```

you can use the global $blog_id to get the current blogid. On a non multisite setup, the blogid will be 0 and should still work when you try to get the posts out the array by

arr[$blog_id]

Comment: This is what I've been considering doing. The only issue I have with it is that it won't work with users who have already been using the plugin, though I suppose I could just write an upgrade function that would move all of the currently stored bookmarks into the new array structure.