# get_user_meta() in multiste with respect to subdomain

Tags: multisite, user-meta

This code allows getting the number of points each user earned.

```
function qa_get_user_point ($user_id) {
  return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'qa_point', true );
}
```

The problem is that in multisite case, the same user may be registered to more than one subsite (subdomain) and that the above code will return the same number of points for all subsites.
In a [similar problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33456/get-user-meta-to-return-user-meta-only-for-current-blog-in-multi-site/33853), they suggest to use `get_user_option()` instead of `get_user_meta`, which is deprecated from wordpress 3.0.0.
I think that the solution should be some thing like this (but didn't work)

```
function qa_get_user_point ($user_id) {
    if ( is_single() ){
        return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'qa_point', true );  // Original    
    }elseif ( is_multisite() ) {        
        return get_user_meta( array( 'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id(),$user_id ), 'qa_point', true );
    }   
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: `get_user_option()` isn't deprecated. What makes you think that? Regardless, if you've saved the points as user meta, then you're not going to be able to retrieve them based on site. That information is lost. You need to set the points with `update_user_option()` to be able to save points per site, which you will then retrieve with `get_user_option()`.

Comment: is this for an existing plugin integration or your own code?

Comment: @majick it is from a theme I'm using

Comment: @JacobPeattie `get_user_option()` isn't working for me and it tells that it is deprecated. In the theme I'm using there is something like this to create points for users `if( !empty( $point->create_question ) ) qa_update_user_point( $post->post_author, $point->create_question );` and to update user's points there is a function called `qa_update_user_point($user_id, $point)`  (taking two arguments)  and in which there is the use of `update_user_meta($user_id, 'qa_point', $new_point);`. Any suggestion?

Comment: If this isn't functionality that you've built yourself, then you need to take it up with the theme author, but it looks like the theme is built so that points are stored globally.  You're not going to be able to retrieve points per site without the theme being changed.

Comment: @JacobPeattie OK, I see. Thank you for your support!

Comment: @Hamed is possible, but may be end up being too difficult to integrate with existing code. see answer for a start.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch and store the data separately on a per blog basis by filtering the user meta update call,  via the [update_user_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/update_(meta_type)_metadata) filter...

```
function myplugin_init() {
    add_filter( 'update_user_metadata', 'myplugin_update_points', 10, 5 );
}

function myplugin_update_points( $null, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ) {

    if ($meta_key == 'qa_point') {

        remove_filter( 'update_user_metadata', 'myplugin_update_points', 10, 5 );            

        global $wpdb; $blog_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix();

        $current_blog_points = get_user_meta( $object_id, $blog_prefix.$meta_key, true );
        $points_change = $meta_value - $prev_value;

        if (!$current_blog_points) {$new_blog_points = $points_change;}
        else {$new_blog_points = $current_blog_points + $points_change;}           

        update_user_meta( $object_id, $blog_prefix.meta_key, $new_blog_points );

        add_filter( 'update_user_metadata', 'myplugin_update_points', 10, 5 );
    }

    // this means: go on with the normal execution in meta.php
    return null;
}
```

This will automatically store points for a blog via an extra user meta entry (only) when the global points are updated. Then you could have a separate function to retrieve those points for user for a blog (2nd argument optional, defaults to current):

```
function myplugin_get_blog_points($user_id, $blog_id=false) {

    if (!$blog_id) {$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();}

    $meta_key = 'qapoint';

    global $wpdb; $blog_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix($blog_id);

    $points = get_user_meta( $user_id, $blog_prefix.'qapoints', true ); 

    return $points;
}
```

Note this may not cover other functions handling points data within the theme, you'd have to check if it modified points via anything besides `update_user_meta` (eg. `delete_user_meta`) and add more code to adapt to that accordingly too. It may or may not be too difficult to be worth the hassle, but it seems possible.

Also note this will note handle points retrospectively, meaning you won't know from which blog the points came if they already exist - that will only start to be recorded once you have code like this in place.

Comment: all that said you may be better off finding a QA plugin that integrates multisite support rather than a theme that doesn't.

Comment: Interesting like Idea. I was thinking to redefine `$point` as an array in which each element corresponds to the blog id. Unfornetly, your code didn't work for me. but the idea is here and I will try to much with theme's existing functions. Thank you Majick.